# SVN cat On Older Revision Location

Tags: svn

Lets say that I have a file that starts in `directory1` and I move the file to `directory2` in `revision 2`. The `Node-copyfrom-rev` in the dump file is `1`. How do I extract the contents of the file based on only knowing where it might have previously been without a certainty of where it will end up in the most up to date working copy?

For instance, if I run

`svn cat -r 1 directory1/file.txt`,

you won't be able to find the file. You need to perform

```
svn cat -r 1 directory2/file.txt
```

which requires knowledge that the file in the working copy exists in directory2 at the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two separate ways of specifying a revision:

1. Using the revision number: `svn -r$rev $URL`
2. Using a *pinned* revision number: `svn $URL@$rev`.

Think of the first way (plain revision number) as giving you a revision of a *file*, and the second way (the *pinned* revision number) as giving you the revision number of the directory.

For example, in revision 10, I did this:

```
$ svn co $REPO/trunk/foo
A foo/foo.txt
A foo/bar.txt
$ cd foo
$ svn delete bar.txt
$ svn commit -m"Removed bar.txt in revision 10"
committed revision 11
```

Now, it's revision 20 and I realize I need to see what `bar.txt` looked like. If I do this:

```
$ svn cat -r10 $REPO/trunk/foo/bar.txt
```

I'll get an error because there is no longer an element in my repository `/trunk/foo/bar.txt`. What I need to do is to also go back to the repository structure back in revision 10. I can do that by *pinning* revision 10 onto the URL:

```
$ svn cat -r10 $REPO/trunk/foo/bar.txt@10
```

That will give me the contents of `bar.txt` at revision 10 as it existed in the repository at revision 10.

---

### Real Life Example

Let's look at my log:

```
$ svn log -v -r161077 $REPO/trunk/Tools/server_tools/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r161077 | dweintraub | 2013-05-23 17:02:03 -0400 (Thu, 23 May 2013) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /trunk/Tools/server_tools/jdescribe.pl

Deleting -- in wrong repository
------------------------------------------------------------------------
$
```

You can see that `jdescribe.pl` was deleted in revision 161077 of my repository. Thus, if I want it, I need to look at revision 161076:

If I do this:

```
$ svn ls -r161076 $REPO/trunk/Tools/server_tools       
find-required-jars.pl
jdescribe.pl
jenkins-bin/
```

There it is, in revision 161076 of the ***directory***:

Let's concatenate out `jdescribe.pl`:

```
$ svn cat -r161076 $REPO/trunk/Tools/server_tools/jdescribe.pl
svn: warning: W160013: '/svn/TravelClickPD/!svn/rvr/161264/trunk/Tools/server_tools/jdescribe.pl' path not found
svn: E200009: Could not cat all targets because some targets don't exist
svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
$
```

Didn't work. There's no `jdescribe.pl` in the current revision of the directory.

Let's add the pinned revision:

```
$ svn cat -r161076 $REPO/trunk/Tools/server_tools/jdescribe.pl@161076 | head 
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# description.pl

use 5.12.0;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use Pod::Usage;
use Getopt::Long;
```

There it is!

Comment: The usual terms are _operative_ and _peg_ _revisions_. See the chapter [Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) in the online book _Version Control with Subversion_.

Comment: Thank you for the informative response :) Question: Can you perform an svn cat on the repository; I thought it could only be applied to working copies. For instance, when I do svn list on the repo, I only get the default svn config files: README.txt
conf/
db/
format
hooks/
locks/

Comment: I tried what you mentioned above. I noticed that doing "svn list" on "directory1@1", I get back file.txt, but when I do "svn cat -r 1 directory1/file.txt@1", I get node not found error.

Comment: @user1431282 - I've updated my answer with a real life example from my repository.